# Is there any function to extract real time NSE or BSE stock price in R

Tags: r, analytics, quantmod, stock

I have been Trying to extract real time data from YAHOO and Google.

```
  getQuote("FCEL.BO",src="yahoo")
  getQuote("FCEL.BO",src="google")
```

but i get everything as Null values as below, the same works for NYSE Stocks.

[image]

How can i get real quote price for these NSE and BSEexchanges.
However can get data by

```
getSymbols("FCEL.BO", src = 'yahoo', from = '2015-10-10', auto.assign =T)
```

But which wont be real time.
How can i get real time Quote

Answer (score 0):

Real time data is not something you can just get for free. You have to subscribe to it and have a private feed to access that kind of data.

This link should help you: 
http://www.nseindia.com/supra_global/content/dotex/data_products.htm